# Happstack: web routes and form data

Tags: haskell, happstack

OK, so yesterday I tried to actually use Happstack for real.

OK, so my actual question. I've got this so far:

```
data LambdaURL =
  URL_CSS   |
  URL_Input |
  URL_Output

instance PathInfo LambdaURL where
  toPathSegments url =
    case url of
      URL_CSS    -> ["Main.css"]
      URL_Input  -> ["Input.html"]
      URL_Output -> ["Output.html"]

  fromPathSegments =
    (segment "Main.css"    >> return URL_CSS   ) <|>
    (segment "Input.html"  >> return URL_Input ) <|>
    (segment "Output.html" >> return URL_Output)

route :: LambdaURL -> RouteT LambdaURL (ServerPartT IO) Response
route url =
  case url of
    URL_CSS    -> serveFile (asContentType "text/css") "Main.css"
    URL_Input  -> ok $ toResponse $ page_Input
    URL_Output -> ok $ toResponse $ page_Output

main = simpleHTTP nullConf $ implSite "www.example.com" "" (setDefault URL_Input $ mkSitePI (runRouteT route))

page_Input :: H.Html

page_Output :: H.Html
```

So that's the tutorial on web-routes. Now I go read the tutorial on forms, and I realise that in order to access form data, you need to be in the `ServerPart` monad, not the `Html` monad. So I end up doing something like

```
generate_page_Output :: ServerPart Response
generate_page_Output = do
  decodeBody (defaultBodyPolicy "." 0 65536 65536)
  expr <- look "expr"
  ok $ toResponse $ page_Output expr

page_Output :: String -> H.Html
```

Now I go modify the `route` function to call `generate_page_Output` rather than `page_Output`. Presumably like this:

```
URL_Output -> generate_page_Output
```

Well, what do you know? That doesn't type-check. `route` lives in the `RouteT` monad, while I'm trying to do stuff in the `ServerPart` monad. Eventually I find `liftRouteT :: m a -> RouteT url m a`. Seems likely, eh? So if I change the line to

```
URL_Output -> liftRouteT generate_page_Output
```

now it compiles. The fun thing is... now the output page URL is HTTP 404. At this point I have absolutely no idea why. I just haven't found the correct function call yet.

Does anybody have a clue how to fix this?

Comment: Is there a reason why this question has been downvoted so much?

Comment: Too much ranting, I guess...

Comment: On the plus side, this question managed to get upvoted all the way back to 0. On the minus side... apparently nobody knows the answer to the actual question. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I realise that in order to access form data, you need to be in the
>   ServerPart monad

That is not quite right. In order to access the form data you need to be in any monad which is an instance of `HasRqData`. `ServerPart` is the base monad that provides that functionality, but the monad transformers like `RouteT` also have `HasRqData` instances which do the lifting automatically.

So, your original generate_page_Output function works if you give it the same return type as `route`

```
generate_page_Output :: RouteT LambdaURL (ServerPartT IO) Response
generate_page_Output = do
  decodeBody (defaultBodyPolicy "." 0 65536 65536)
  expr <- look "expr"
  ok $ toResponse $ page_Output expr
```

No `lifeRouteT` required.

The output page is probably 404 because you did not supply an `expr` value for `look` to find, so it fails. If you want the `expr` to be optional then you should do:

```
  expr <- optional $ look "expr"
```

which will make `expr` a `Maybe` value. `optional` comes from `Control.Applicative`.

Here is a working version:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Control.Applicative
import Data.Monoid
import Happstack.Server
import Happstack.Server
import Text.Blaze.Html5 ((!))
import qualified Text.Blaze.Html5 as H
import qualified Text.Blaze.Html5.Attributes as A
import Web.Routes
import Web.Routes.Happstack


data LambdaURL =
  URL_CSS   |
  URL_Input |
  URL_Output

instance PathInfo LambdaURL where
  toPathSegments url =
    case url of
      URL_CSS    -> ["Main.css"]
      URL_Input  -> ["Input.html"]
      URL_Output -> ["Output.html"]

  fromPathSegments =
    (segment "Main.css"    >> return URL_CSS   ) <|>
    (segment "Input.html"  >> return URL_Input ) <|>
    (segment "Output.html" >> return URL_Output)

route :: LambdaURL -> RouteT LambdaURL (ServerPartT IO) Response
route url =
  case url of
    URL_CSS    -> serveFile (asContentType "text/css") "Main.css"
    URL_Input  -> ok $ toResponse $ page_Input
    URL_Output -> generate_page_Output

main = simpleHTTP nullConf $ implSite "www.example.com" "" (setDefault URL_Input $ mkSitePI (runRouteT route))

page_Input :: H.Html
page_Input =
    H.html $ do
      H.head $ do
        H.title "input"
      H.body $ do
       H.p $ H.a ! A.href "Output.html?expr=foo" $ "output"


page_Output :: String -> H.Html
page_Output expr =
    H.html $ do
      H.head $ do
        H.title "output"
      H.body $ do
        H.p $ do "expr is: "
                 H.toHtml expr

generate_page_Output :: RouteT LambdaURL (ServerPartT IO) Response
generate_page_Output = do
  decodeBody (defaultBodyPolicy "." 0 65536 65536)
  expr <- look "expr"
  ok $ toResponse $ page_Output expr
```

Comment: Holy hell... Sure enough, if I supply the `expr` parameter in the query URL, the page pops up just fine, no code modification required. o_O I had no idea that not finding a parameter made the whole thing 404; I assumed I'd just get an empty string back...

Comment: I need to rearrange my code to bring `LambdaURL` into scope in the module where `genereate_page_Output` is defined... but it would certainly simplify things to keep all the types the same. If only it were a bit easier to figure out which monads let you do what...

Comment: Do you know where `optional` is defined? What do I need to import?